# Free JavaScript chessboard 

Tags: javascript, chess

Could anybody suggest a free (as in freedom) and open source JavaScript chessboard?
My plan is to hook it up with some server-side Python code, most probably it will be the flask web framework.

I need a really minimal set of features:

- a way to display a position on the board (not only the initial one) when generating the HTML code by the server-side script. The position can be stored in a list of lists (to emulate a two-dimensional array) and optionally in a FEN (Forsyth-Edwards Notation) string.
- a way to make moves (by dragging pieces with the mouse cursor) and have the moves automatically submitted to the server-side script via HTTP POST. Validation of moves by the JavaScript code is not mandatory, because I can do this server-side.

Answer (score 9):

I just released http://chessboardjs.com at v0.1.0 and it seems to fit all of your requirements.

It's open source under the MIT license (ie: as in freedom)

Comment: This is a very nice board..

Answer (score 4):

You can check this:
[htmlchess.sourceforge.net](http://htmlchess.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4):

Try [pgn4web](http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/home.html). It supports PGN strings and even Chess960. Very easy to customize.

Comment: I use this on a chess forum (SMFforum software), works great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to try [jChess](https://github.com/bmarini/jchess), a jQuery plugin that looks promising.  However, I don't think the user can move the pieces out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [chess board](http://chessboardjs.com/) which will definitely satisfy your needs. Out of the box it has:

- set up fen position
- multiple boards set up
- moving pieces, removing pieces, adding pieces
- different themes of pieces
- flipping the board
- and a lot of other things

It is easy to set up (just by doing the following):

**JavaScript**

```
var ruyLopez = 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R';
var board = new ChessBoard('board', ruyLopez);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
```

You can get

[image]

Comment: link??????????????????????????

Comment: @KevinDeus Sorry for some reason when I was pasting this the link disappeared. Fixed it.